# How can you get a js/coffee variable inside a rails expression within a coffee file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Given the line

`'car': '<%= I18n.t('url.car', locale: :sv) %>'`

is in a `mysite.coffee.erb` file in a rails app.
I would like to dynamically set that locale from a js variable, but cant figure out the syntax to make it work, is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not going to work, and not possible. not thinking!